# default value for a pointer parameter

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to create a class for employees, and have a problem with its constructor.

My class looks like that (please note the name parameter which is `char*` type):

```cpp
class Employee {
    int id;
    char * name ;
    float salary;
    int hours;
    int extra;

public:
    //constructor
    Employee(int, char *, float, int, int);

    //Getters and Setters:
    void setId(int a) { id = a; }
    int getId() { return id; }
    void setName(char * c) { name = c; }
    char * getName() { return name; }
    void setSalary(float f) { salary = f; }
    float getSalary() { return salary; }
    void setHours(int h) { hours = h; }
    int getHours() { return hours; }
    void setExtra(int e) { extra = e; }
    int getExtra() { return extra; }
};
```

I built a constructor and I want it to have default parameters, and I don't know how to deal with the name parameter to have a default of let's say "unknown".

This is the constructor:

```cpp
Employee::Employee(int i = 123456789, char * na, float sal = 30, int ho = 45, int ex = 10)
{
    id = i;
    name = na;
    salary = sal;
    hours = ho;
    extra = ex;
}
```

Comment: This is not how you write C++. Where are you learning this from?

Comment: Use member initialization lists. Employee::Employee(): id(i), name(na), etc. Also why have defaults when you should be having a default constructor Employee::Employee() that will set those values for you.

Comment: also use `std::string`

Comment: You can't have a non-defaulted parameter after a defaulted parameter. And you need to specify the default values in the declaration, not in the implementation

Comment: @OmidCompSCI If the constructor has the default parameter for `na` as OP wants, then the constructor is a default constructor.

Comment: @NeilButterworthNo why is that? could you elaborate? I am using cpp sites as cppreference.com (preparing to my next course in college)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a character array, and initialise the array to point to the first element of the array. You can store the array for example as a static member:

```
// in the class definition
inline static char default_name[] = "unknown";

// in argument list of the constructor
... char * na = default_name, ...
```

Although, you may want to consider whether it makes sense for `name` to be pointer to non-const. Perhaps a pointer to const would suffice. In such case, you could initialise it to point to the literal `"unknown"` directly.

Comment: Or, once you've fixed the almost-certainly missing `const` or switched to `std::string`, just literally write it inline...

Comment: Can you elaborate more, please?
Is the idea to have a "blank" pointer attribute (with the name "default_name") to the literal "unknown"?
also, why const is sufficing if I don't know the length of the name?

Comment: @e.ad The idea is to have an array that contains the default name, and by default set the pointer to point to (first element of) that array. A pointer does not need to know the length of an array in order to point at an element of that array.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner version

```
class Employee {
    int id = 0;
    char *name = nullptr;
    float salary = 0.0;
    int hours = 0;
    int extra = 0;
```

And you don't need to have constructors, this depends on the case, but you get the idea that by initializing the variables on the definition you reduce the inconsistency of having multiples constructors for example

Comment: And Employee() = default should be added

Comment: got it. can you please give me an example of a case that that building and default constructor will not suffice?